# Opening Result of WKWebView Javascript Injection in Safari View Controller

Tags: javascript, ios, xcode, swift, wkwebview

I have a `WKWebView` that I'm using to modify a webpage before letting the user interact with it. I'd like to be able to use a javascript injection to programmatically click a button `(document.getElementById("id").click())` and then load the resulting webpage in a Safari View Controller. I'm familiar with `WKWebView` and the `evaluateJavascript()` method, but I'm unsure of how to transfer the result of a programmatically triggered button click to a Safari View Controller. How would I do this? I would use a Safari View Controller in the first place, but there doesn't seem to be support for injecting scripts.

```
//various other modifications to webpage precede this
//target button is a 'next' button on webpage
//would like to "click" this button and open the next page in safari vc
//The code below opens the next page in WKWebView

let next = "document.getElementById('\(id)').click()"
webView.evaluateJavaScript(next) { (result, error) in
                print("Result: \(result)")
                print("Error: \(error)")
            }
```

Comment: Please show the code of what you've tried so far.

Comment: Question has been edited with sample code